# Verilog ISE compiler error: syntax error near if statement

Tags: verilog

Below is my code:

```
task CheckTxDataFunc;
 input  [39:0] ExpectPattern0;
 input  [39:0] ExpectPattern1;
 output reg CheckTxDataFunc_Bit;
 reg Equal00;
 reg Equal01;
 reg Equal10;
 reg Equal11;

 begin
    CompareTxData(ExpectPattern1, ExpectPattern0, Equal11, Equal00);  
    CompareTxData(ExpectPattern0, ExpectPattern1, Equal01, Equal10);  
    CheckTxDataFunc_Bit = (Equal11 & Equal00) | (Equal10 &       Equal01);                            
 end
endtask

reg              checktxdata_bit;

initial begin

CheckTxDataFunc(64'h0000_0000__0000_1110, 64'h0000_0000__0000_2222, checktxdata_bit)
**if (checktxdata_bit) begin**
   $display("Message at time : %t ,Transmit data held", $time);
   end
else begin
   TestError = TestError + 1;
   $display("Error: Held transmit data incorrect. Expect %h %h, Received %h %h", TxPattern1, TxPattern0, 64'h0000_0000__0000_1110, 64'h0000_0000__0000_2222);
   end

end
```

I am getting an error *"Syntax error near if"* for the line `if (checktxdata_bit) begin`.

Please help, I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: can you please clean your code a bit and improve some indentation to make it easier to see whats going on?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a semicolon on the line before the error.